# Limit of a sequence defined by a sum: $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac1{2^n}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1{\sqrt k}\binom nk$

Tags: calculus, limits

$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt k}\binom{n}{k}$

Could it have a connection to Euler summability?

Comment: You could use Stirling's approximation

Comment: Recently posted question about the same limit: [Find $ \lim\limits_{{n \to \infty}} \frac1{2^n} \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac1{\sqrt{k}} \binom nk$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2247052)

Comment: This question seems to have been here first and it was posted before there was a great concern about context (not that the duplicate source has much context other than "I thought about Stirling's approximation but didn't get anything by applying it").

Answer (score 3):

Here is another approach using Cauchy-Schwarz: We have
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac1{\sqrt{k}} \cdot \dbinom{n}k & \leq \sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac1{\sqrt{k}^2}} \cdot \sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n \dbinom{n}k^2}\\
& = \sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac1k} \cdot \sqrt{\dbinom{2n}n-1}\\
& \leq \sqrt{\ln(n)+1} \cdot \sqrt{\dbinom{2n}n} \sim \sqrt{\ln(n)} \sqrt{\dfrac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi n}}}
\end{align}
Hence,
$$\dfrac1{2^n}\sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac1{\sqrt{k}} \cdot \dbinom{n}k \in \mathcal{O}\left( \sqrt{\dfrac{\ln(n)}{\sqrt{\pi n}}}\right)$$
Hence, $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac1{2^n}\sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac1{\sqrt{k}} \cdot \dbinom{n}k = 0$$

Answer (score 0):

$$
\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt k}\binom{n}{k} = \frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{k=1}^{\log n-1} \frac{1}{\sqrt k}\binom{n}{k} + \frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{k=\log n}^{n} \frac{1}{\sqrt k}\binom{n}{k}
$$
The second term is upper bounded by 
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{\log n}}\cdot\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{k=\log n}^{n} \binom{n}{k} \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{\log n}}\cdot\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\log n}}\cdot 1 \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 0
$$ 
and the first one by
$$
\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{k=1}^{\log n-1} \binom{n}{k} \leq \log n\cdot\frac{1}{2^n} \binom{n}{\log n}
$$ 
What can you say about this last thing?

Comment: You should add \floor for the index I think

Comment: For complete accuracy, yes. Does not change anything to the argument, though -- just makes the typing more cumbersome.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, more self-contained (no need to know anything about Stirling, or non-trivial properties of the binomial coefficients)

Fix any $\epsilon > 0$, and let $N_\epsilon\geq 1$ be an integer such that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{N_\epsilon}} < \epsilon$. Then, for any $n\geq N_\epsilon$, we can write
$$
\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt k}\binom{n}{k} = \underbrace{\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{k=1}^{N_\epsilon-1} \frac{1}{\sqrt k}\binom{n}{k}}_A + \underbrace{\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{k=N_\epsilon}^{n} \frac{1}{\sqrt k}\binom{n}{k}}_B
$$
Now, it is easy to see that $A\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 0$, as there are constantly many terms (i.e., $N_\epsilon - 1$), each of them going to $0$ (recall that for any $0\leq k \leq N_\epsilon$, $\frac{1}{\sqrt k}\binom{n}{k}\leq \binom{n}{k} \leq n^k$, and you divide by $2^n$). In other terms, there exists $N^\ast\geq 1$ such that for all $n \geq N^\ast$ one has $A \leq \epsilon$.

It remains to bound $B$: by choice of $N_\epsilon$,
$$
B \leq \epsilon\cdot\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{k=N_\epsilon}^{n}\binom{n}{k} \leq \epsilon\cdot\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{n}{k} = \epsilon
$$

Putting it together, for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $N=\max(N_\epsilon, N^\ast)$ such that for all $n\geq N$
$$
\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt k}\binom{n}{k} \leq A+B \leq 2\epsilon
$$
proving that $\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt k}\binom{n}{k} \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 0$.